# my android hello world layout is not like good tutorial's shows

Tags: android, xml, layout

i'm starting with android development , and i'm following the Google's training classes ,  everything was ok , and when i run the first layout its looks different from whats is shown in the tutorial page.

There is the look of tutorial:

[image]

There is mine

[image]

so , the question is, what is wrong with my layout code above?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/button_send"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try the same XML with `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. See if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `android:orientation="horizontal"`, which makes me think that RelativeLayout is supposed to be a LinearLayout. Replace the `<RelativeLayout ...>` and `</RelativeLayout>` with `<LinearLayout ...>` and `</LinearLayout>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"` to your edit text if you need to keep the relative layout.